# Converting String to Date when using functional WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux

When we send a URL with request parameters that needs to be converted to date, in SpringMVC we can do something like the code below in the controller and the fasterxml json library does the automatic conversion!

```
public String getFare(@@RequestParam(value = "flightDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate date)
```

But how to achieve the same when we use the HandlerFunction (Spring webflux)? For example, in my HandlerFunction

```
public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> getFare = serverRequest ->
      {
       Optional<String> flightDate   = serverRequest.queryParam("flightDate");
     }
```

The code `serverRequest.queryParam("flightDate")` gives a String. Is it possible to get the same automatic conversion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (you can look at [Spring's source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerRequest.java#L204) and see that no other way to get the `queryParams` other than getting it as `Optional<String>`)
You must convert the field to `Date` yourself

```java
Date flightDate = request.queryParam("flightDate ")
                         .map(date -> {
                             try {
                                 return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(date);
                             } catch (ParseException e) {
                                 return null;
                             }
                         }).orElse(null);
```